# Pattern matching with lidR's LAS Catalog

Tags: r, lidr

Pattern matching can be used to read specific tiles with `readLAScatalog`. For example:

```
(als <- readLAScatalog(here("als/2normalized/voxels"), pattern="*.10m.laz"))
```

However, can "OR" statements (or similar) be used to specify two conditions? For example:

```
(als <- readLAScatalog(here("als/2normalized/voxels"), pattern="*.10m.laz" | pattern="*.25m.laz"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LAS files pass a lot of the parameters to `list.files`, so the same logic that applies there should apply with readLAScatalog.

So if you can construct a *regular expression* that matches just the files you want then you can do that. For example, I think this is what you want:

```
> list.files(".",pattern="\\.10m\\.laz$|\\.25m\\.laz$")
[1] "a.10m.laz" "a.25m.laz" "b.10m.laz" "b.25m.laz"
```

This matches either of the two patterns either side of the | symbol. Note the use of `\\.` to match a literal dot in the string (in a regexp, a `.` matches any single character) and the $ to tie the match to the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly!